# obtener un String desde una peticion VolleySingleton enAndroid

Tags: php, android, base-de-datos, android-volley

tengo una base de datos en un servidor externo, quiero comprobar que el valor que el usuario ha introducido para un campo no exista en una columna de mi tabla previamente, si es así avisarlo e impedirle que avance en la aplicación.
Uso este codigo php para conectar con el servidor:

```
<?php
/**
 * Obtiene el detalle de una meta especificada por
 * su identificador 
 */

require 'pistes.php';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {

    if (isset($_GET['nom_usuari'])) {

        // Obtener parámetro idMeta
        $parametro = $_GET['nom_usuari'];

        // Tratar retorno
        $retorno = pistes::getByNom_usuari($parametro);


        if ($retorno) {

            $pistes["estado"] = "1";
            $pistes["pistes"] = $retorno;
            // Enviar objeto json de la meta
            print json_encode($pistes);
        } else {
            // Enviar respuesta de error general
            print json_encode(
                array(
                    'estado' => '2',
                    'mensaje' => 'No se obtuvo el registro'
                )
            );
        }

    } else {
        // Enviar respuesta de error
        print json_encode(
            array(
                'estado' => '3',
                'mensaje' => 'Se necesita un identificador'
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Uso volley Singleton para hacer la peticion:

```
 bt_acabar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //validació de que el nom de la partida i el nom de l'usuari no existeixin a la taula
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                VolleySingleton.
                        getInstance(getApplicationContext()).
                        addToRequestQueue(
                                new JsonObjectRequest(
                                        Request.Method.GET,
                                        "http://gimcana.esy.es/obtenir_pistes_nom_partida.php?nom_partida="
                                                +nom_partida.getText().toString(),
                                        jsonObject,
                                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                                // Procesar la respuesta Json
                                                String estado = null;

                                                try {
                                                    estado = response.getString("estado");
                                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }

                                                switch (estado) {
                                                    case "1":
                                                       resposta="invalid";


                                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "el nom de la partida ja ha estat utilitzat, creen un altre",
                                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        break;
                                                    case "2":

                                                        resposta="correcte";

                                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "nom de la partida correcte", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        break;
                                            }
                                        }},
                                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                                                resposta= "invalid";

                                                Log.d( TAG,"Error Volley: " + error.getMessage());
                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error en la comprobació del nom de la partida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        }

                                )


                        );
```

Los **toasts** que obtengo me indican que estoy haciendo correctamente el proceso, pero cuando vuelvo al hilo principal, la variable `resposta` es **null**, con lo cual la comprobación no me sirve para nada...

Lo intento hacer así:

```
if(reposta=="correcte"){
  Intent intent = new Intent(setAct.this, segAct.class);
                Bundle b=new Bundle();
                intent.putExtra("nom_part",nom_partida.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("nom_usuari",nom_usuari.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("num_equips",num_equips.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("contras_usu",contras_usu.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(intent);
}
```

el debugger me dice que el valor de resposta es **null**, me imagino que esto sucede por que son dos hilos distintos, alguién me puede ayudar??

Gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

La llamada que estás haciendo es asíncrona por lo que puedes estar ejecutando tu bloque de código que crea el bundle antes de que obtengas la respuesta.

En lugar de usar Toast, pon un punto de interrupción en el bloque del onResponse de Volley y otro en el inicio del bloque donde creas el Bundle, así verás que se ejecuta antes, si el onResponse o el bloque del Bundle.

Mi consejo es que te crees un callback para recoger la respuesta de Volley y sepas cuando ha terminado la petición al servicio.

Saludos.